# can i give my child's last name as "ar rahman " like "insha Ar Rahman "

Tags: halal-haram, quran, naming

Is it ok to name a baby as "Insha Ar Rahman "
Or Insha Rahman is better?

Comment: You want to name a baby "If the Most Merciful wills"? Why would you use a sentence as a name?

Comment: Brother keep a name which is really meaningful.

Comment: Why isn't it meaningful?  Will of the most merciful... is it meaning less as a name?

Comment: Ar-Rahman can only safely be connected to servant of ('Abd) anything else is at least frowned upon. And this is addressed in several posts.